# When using SELECT only 3 rows are returned, when using UPDATE, why are many rows affected?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When I run the query

```
SELECT * from AC where ACID in ('1','2','3')
```

I get 3 rows returned. Each row in the table has a unique ACID. However, when I try to update StartDateTime in only those 3 rows using

```
UPDATE AC set StartDateTime = '2019-09-30 00:00:00.000' where ACID in ('1','2','3')
```

I get the following:

(3 row(s) affected)

(12 row(s) affected)

(3 row(s) affected)

How can so many rows be updated when only 3 were supposed to be updated? Is this table linked to another in some way?

Comment: What other fields are present in your table? Do you have any other tables that are linked to this one by foreign key relationships?

Comment: The output shows that there were **3** sets of results; it's showing that your `SELECT` returned 3 results, but then `12` rows were effected, followed by (probably) the same 3 from your original `SELECT`. I suspect you have a trigger on your table `AC` and another table is being effected.

Comment: This is most likely an update from UPDATE trigger!

Comment: @RobStreeting Only one foreign key relationship exists and nothing on that table has been modified for quite some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Larnu @tgralex I believe this is the answer, but it is not updating a different table, it is updating itself. There are two triggers in the AC table and they are both for updating an EndDateTime in the AC table when a row is detected with a StartDateTime after the previous most recent StartDateTime so that periods do not overlap. The first `(3 row(s) affected)` was for updating the StartDateTime that I had initially mentioned, the second `(12 row(s) affected)` was for checking all of the rows that had a Location in common with the three ACIDs that I was updating, and the last `(3 row(s) updated)` was for updating the EndDateTime for the previous most recent StartDateTime for the three ACIDs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems very likely that this is because you have cascading updates on a foreign key relation, probably two levels deep. The first `(3 row(s) affected)` is from updating the grandchild rows of this table (the child rows of the child rows); the second `(12 row(s) affected)` is from updating the child rows of this table; and the last `(3 row(s) updated)` is from updating this table.

It's possible that rather than a foreign key relation, this is happening because of an explicit UPDATE trigger as @Larnu and @tgralex suggested in comments -- but this seems less likely to me; if you'd written triggers for your table you'd probably know about them.

Comment: I did not actually write the table, which is why I did not think to look at the triggers, but those triggers appear to be the reason for the update. No other foreign key tables received any updates.